# What is the difference between these versions of Maven artifact jersey-grizzly2?

Tags: java, maven, jersey, grizzly

Sample Maven dependency block:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-grizzly2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

On Maven Central, I see:

- 10-Jun-2015: 1.18.4
- 11-Feb-2015: 1.19

The older release has a higher version number.  This puzzles me.

My Google-fu fails me here.  I can find nothing about this Maven artifact on the official Jersey and Grizzly docs.

Which one is best to use (considered "latest")?

Ref: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.jersey%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jersey-grizzly2%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's interesting, there was probably a mistake made when `jersey-grizzly2` was released.

You can be assured that [`jersey-grizzly2:1.19`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-grizzly2/1.19) was released on Feb 11, 2015 and that [`jersey-grizzly2:1.18.4`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-grizzly2/1.18.4) was released on Jun 09, 2015. You can also see that on the directory tree of Maven Central for both artifacts ([here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-grizzly2/1.19/) and [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-grizzly2/1.18.4/)).

Like you, I can't find any reference about this, but don't worry, the published date on Maven Central doesn't lie: `1.18.4` released on Jun 09, 2015 is *newer* than 1.19 released on Feb 11, 2015.

Note however that from the [list of modules](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#modules) of latest Jersey 2.22 documentation, you should use [`jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet/2.22.1) instead.